# Haskell Convert a Maybe to a defined Type

Tags: haskell

I'm in my first few days of learning Haskell and I'm struggle with the `Maybe`  type that is being returned from the Haskell's `find` function. I defined a function called `FindNextState` which takes in a tuple, and 2 Strings. This funcition calls `getListOfNextStates` which uses a lambda and pattern matching to get a list from the passed in tuple and then uses the `find` function's predicate I find a match in that list. The problem is find returns return a `Maybe` of my Transition type, this is preventing me from calling my `getToState` function because it's expecting at Transition. Is there anyway to convert the `Maybe` returned by find function?

**Code**

```
type State = String
type Symbol = String
type Transisition = (State, Symbol, State)

states = ["s0","s1"]
initState = "s0"
finalStates = ["s3"]
transisitionList = [("s0", "0", "s1"), ("s0", "1", "s1")]
dfa = (states, initState, finalStates, transisitionList)

getToState :: Transisition -> State
getToState  (_, _, toState) = toState


findNextState :: DFA -> State -> Symbol -> Maybe Transisition --Maybe Transisition is the issue, I need it to be my type of Transisition otherwise Haskell throws an error when I load my program 
findNextState (_,_,_,tList) state symbol =  getListOfNextStates tList state symbol

getListOfNextStates :: [Transisition] -> State -> Symbol -> Maybe Transisition
getListOfNextStates tList state symbol = find(\(sState,sym,eState) -> matchTransition state symbol (sState,sym,eState)) tList
```

**Sample Input**

```
findNextState dfa "s2" "0"
Just ("s2","0","s3")

*Main> :t findNextState dfa "s2" "0"
findNextState dfa "s2" "0" :: Maybe Transisition
```

** Desired Code**

```
findNextState :: DFA -> State -> Symbol -> State
findNextState (_,_,_,tList) state symbol = getToState( (getListOfNextStates tList state symbol) )
```

Comment: What do you want it to do if it doesn't find a match?

Comment: I’d be fine with just returning a hardcode string value that says something like “failed”

Comment: Right now it returns `Nothing` if it doesn't find a match, which is a really good standard way of encoding a failure state. If you want `findNextState` to return `Transition` then you need to encode your failure state as a `Transition` somehow (you can't just return a string since that isn't a `Transition`). If you do that, the failure would be passed to `getToState` and processed, as if it was a successful find, which is probably not what you want. Leaving it as a `Maybe` is probably the preferred option, and you can use a case statement/pattern matching to extract the value.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're comfortable with the program just crashing with an error on a failed find, you can use [`fromJust :: Maybe a -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromJust). Not recommended in general, but it has its uses.

Comment: @DarthFennec I apologize, I'm very unfamiliar with this language. Are you saying I could create a function fromJust like this: `fromJust :: Maybe Transisition-> Transisition`
`fromJust a = a`

Comment: I don't mind if the program crashes at this point. So the `fromJust` implementation seems very appealing. Do you have an example of this, maybe a website that uses `fromjust`?

Comment: "Are you saying I could create a function fromJust like this:" No, it wouldn't be implemented like that. `fromJust` is a standard library function, included in the `Data.Maybe` package. My earlier comment has a link to the documentation. If you were to implement it yourself, you'd do something like this: `fromJust :: Maybe a -> a  //  fromJust (Just x) = x  //  fromJust Nothing = error "illegal fromJust Nothing encountered, crashing"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend keeping the `Maybe`, as it allows the code to fail gracefully if it doesn't find a match. If you do that, you'll leave `getListOfNextStates` returning `Maybe Transition`, and then change `findNextState` to return `Maybe State`. Now you can define it like this:

```
findNextState :: DFA -> State -> Symbol -> Maybe State
findNextState (_,_,_,tList) state symbol = case newstate of
    Just s -> Just (getToState s)
    Nothing -> Nothing
  where newstate = getListOfNextStates tList state symbol
```

Or more succinctly, you can use [`fmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:fmap) (or its infix version, `<$>`) like so:

```
findNextState :: DFA -> State -> Symbol -> Maybe State
findNextState (_,_,_,tList) state symbol = getToState <$> newstate
  where newstate = getListOfNextStates tList state symbol
```

---

If you really don't think there will be a failed find, or you just don't care, you can use [`fromJust :: Maybe Transition -> Transition`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromJust), like so:

```
import Data.Maybe

getListOfNextStates :: [Transisition] -> State -> Symbol -> Transisition
getListOfNextStates tList state symbol = fromJust (find (\(sState,sym,eState) -> matchTransition state symbol (sState,sym,eState)) tList)
```

This will throw an exception if `getListOfNextStates` returns `Nothing`, effectively crashing the program. I wouldn't do this in real code unless you can absolutely ensure that it will never happen.

Comment: Seeing this put the `fromJust` in prospective for me. For this particular use case I think I'm safe if the program crashes on bad input otherwise the `fmap` would definitively be the right way to go. Thank you so much for the help!